# How to tell which NVIDIA cards support ECC

Tags: centos, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I'd like to write a code block that checks if a given NVIDIA GPU Card supports ECC or not. I was going to import the list (as csv/text) and iterate over it but I can't seem to find any authoritative source that lists NVIDIA GPUs that support/don't support ECC.

I found [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/modern-list-of-ecc-enabled-quadro-and-tesla-cards/72749) in NVIDIA Forum and it doesn't look like NVIDIA provides this list. So, my question is - is there a way to tell if a card supports the feature without actually having access to the card itself? (e.g if in your historical nvidia-smi output file, a certain field is 'this' value, then ...)

There is a list of GPUs (subset provided below) that I want this information for. Is the solution going to NVIDIA website for each card's specs and populating the list manually? Any suggestions?

(The following list is extracted from a bunch of nvidia-smi outputs for various hosts - old outputs from commands that someone ran without any flags and saved as txt file.)

GeForce GTX 108... ( I assume this is 1080 TI)
GeForce GTX 1080
GeForce GTX TIT... (I assume this is TITAN X)
GeForce GTX 780
Tesla K80
Tesla K40c
Tesla K20m
Tesla M2090
Tesla P100-PCIE... (Not sure, but [maybe this](https://images.nvidia.com/content/tesla/pdf/nvidia-tesla-p100-PCIe-datasheet.pdf)).
Tesla P40 etc. ( the list could grow as I encounter them)

Comment: The most comprehensive list would be the GPUZ database, but I don't know if it's publicly accessible.

Comment: @spikey_richie Which one are you referring to? I see no exact match when I do a quick google search for "GPUZ database". I know you said it may not be publicly accessible", but I'd expect at least something written about it somewhere. Could you provide a link please

Comment: @elegantcomplexity Probably [TechPowerUp: GPU Specs Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/).

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/modern-list-of-ecc-enabled-quadro-and-tesla-cards/72749/4

Comment: ECC support is actually a soft switch on the card.  You can use nvidia-smi to flip the switch, after which a reboot is required.   So you can't find out by checking card model.   All of nvidia-smi is available in the nvml library, look in there.  (nvidia-smi is written with nvml)  Note however, that this API (like all the rest of cuda) changes and you will probably need to update your code to track cuda versions.